# Performing SQL query programatically with Java Collections/Map

Tags: java, sql, collections, hashmap

I have 2 tables with a stringColum in common as below:

Table A (full):

```
stringColum       doubleColumn
name a            1
name a            2
name b            5
name b            4
name b            1
name c            2
[...]
```

Table B (may have some missing values in stringColum present in TableA):

```
stringColum       doubleColumn
name b            10
name b            20
name b            30
name c            11
[...]
```

How can I get an object with its values summed by doubleColumn and grouped by stringColum as below (I mean, do this for table A and B so I can compare them after this)?

Table A (summed/grouped):

```
stringColum       doubleColumn
name a            3
name b            10
name c            2
[...]
```

Table B (summed/grouped):

```
stringColum       doubleColumn
name b            60
name c            11
[...]
```

Instead of using SQL/JPQL to perform DB join/group, how can I do that with Collections as I've started below?

```
List<UorPos> uorsList = uf.findAllUPB();
List<Treinamentos> treinamentosList = tf.findAll();

Map<String, Double> orcMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Double> rlzMap = new HashMap<>();

for (UorPos u : uorsList) {
    orcMap.put(u.getNomeUorPos(), u.getOrc());
}

for (Treinamentos r : treinamentosList) {
    rlzMap.put(r.getDivisao(), r.getValorCurso());
}
```

The for loop above gets only the first pair of register from the table. E.g.: 
TableA resultList after the for loop (similar to TableB resultList):

```
stringColum       doubleColumn
name a            1
name b            5
name c            2
[...]
```

How can I get all the values and then sum them, grouping by the stringColumn?

After that, I'll need to compare the stringColumn present in the two tables, filling Table B with the pair 'missingString Column','0'. E.g.:

Table B (summed/grouped):

```
stringColum       doubleColumn
name a            0 // --> this pair of register will be inserted in TableB if a stringColum present in TableA doesn't exist in the Table B
name b            60
name c            11
[...]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use a SQL join/group? That will most likely be easier to write and more efficient to run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To group and sum use the following code:

```
    for (UorPos u : uorsList) {
        orcMap.merge(u.getNomeUorPos(), u.getOrc(), (x, y) -> x + y);
    }

    for (Treinamentos r : treinamentosList) {
        rlzMap.merge(r.getDivisao(), r.getValorCurso(), (x, y) -> x + y);
    }
```

or if you don't use Java 8:

```
    for (UorPos u : uorsList) {
        String key = u.getNomeUorPos();
        if (orcMap.containsKey(key)) {
            orcMap.put(key, orcMap.get(key) + u.getOrc());
        } else {
            orcMap.put(key, u.getOrc());
        }
    }

    for (Treinamentos r : treinamentosList) {
        String key = r.getDivisao();
        if (rlzMap.containsKey(key)) {
            rlzMap.put(key, rlzMap.get(key) + r.getValorCurso());
        } else {
            rlzMap.put(key, r.getValorCurso());
        }
    }
```

To add missing items to the second map use the following code:

```
    for (String key : orcMap.keySet()) {
        rlzMap.putIfAbsent(key, 0.0);
    }
```

or if you don't use Java 8:

```
    for (String key : orcMap.keySet()) {
        if (!rlzMap.containsKey(key)) {
            rlzMap.put(key, 0.0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi vbezhenar! Man, can you provide a version with no Lambda expression, since I'm using Java 7. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't use the `merge` and `putIfAbsent` , since I'm using JDK 7. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Those methods are indeed from Java 8. I added Java 7 versions.